# send data from asp.net to webforms cliet from time to time

Tags: wcf

I have a windows forms application. I need to send data to it whenever something happens on the server.

How should I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need notification from the server of the event, so I would open a persistent TCP connection to the server and listen for the notification. This means you'll have to write the server for it to connect to.

Alternatively, you could connect only periodically and check for notifications. You would put the connection on a Timer control and set the interval in the config, or maybe even user settings.

If you're in the MS world, this is what WCF is for...it makes it pretty easy, though WCF configuration is a black art in and of itself.